# How to import wasm file generated by wasm-pack inside typescript file?

Tags: typescript, rust, webassembly, deno

Steps:

`cargo generate --git https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template`

Project name: `project-name`

```rust
// src/lib.rsj
mod utils;

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[cfg(feature = "wee_alloc")]
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[wasm_bindgen]
struct Temp;

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Temp {
    pub fn hello() -> String {
        String::from("QWE")
    }
}
```

`Cargo.toml` has all necessary details:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[features]
default = ["console_error_panic_hook"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.63"

console_error_panic_hook = { version = "0.1.6", optional = true }

wee_alloc = { version = "0.4.5", optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
wasm-bindgen-test = "0.3.13"

[profile.release]
opt-level = "s"
```

In project directory execute commands:

```sh
# builds and makes pkg directory in root directory with .js .ts and .wasm files
wasm-pack build

mkdir deno
touch deno/main.ts
```

```
// deno/main.ts

const filename = "<absolute-path>/pkg/project_name_bg.wasm";
const wasmCode = await Deno.readFile(filename);
const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmCode);
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule);
const {
    Temp,
} = wasmInstance.exports;

console.log(Temp);
```

And finally, in project root directory:

```sh
deno run --allow-read deno/main.ts
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: WebAssembly.Instance(): Imports argument must be present and must be 
an object
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule);
                     ^
    at file:///.../project-name/deno/main.ts:5:22
```

Here's what I am trying to do: I would like to generate `.wasm` file from rust files (using `wasm-pack`), import that file inside `.ts` file and execute with `deno`. But I can't fix the last step.

I tried using [wasi](https://deno.land/std@0.75.0/wasi), didn't work.
Going through the steps above and using `node`/`js` instead `deno`/`ts` works fine with the help of the [rustwasm guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/introduction.html).

But

How can I achieve what I mentioned above using `deno` + `ts`?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor requires `imports` object:

```js
const imports = { };
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, imports);
```